# Четыре вопроса по мобильной верстке

Tags: mobile-web, css

Привет. Возникли четыре вопроса по верстке для мобильных устройств.

1. На стареньком андроиде с ОС версии 4.0.4 (Sony Ericsson mk16i, стандартный браузер android) наблюдается такой эффект при переворачивании устройства в landscape-положение:

[image: Imgur]

верхний навбар с position: fixed превращается в странную белую полоску:

[image: Imgur]

Что это такое, откуда возникает, и как с этим бороться?

2. iphone 4 на подобный поворот никак не реагирует, оставляя навбару ту же ширину, что и была. Я справился с этим багом с помощью js, но есть ли какой-то общепринятый подход к подобным вещам?

3. При достаточном разрешении показывается вертикальное боковое меню, также закрепленное с помощью position: fixed. при увеличении масштаба оно также масштабируется и закрывает собой полэкрана, оставаясь закрепленным на месте. Есть ли способ разместить его относительно window, а не viewport, не прибегая к position: absolute или js? Бонусом - какую библиотеку сейчас модно использовать для обнаружения планшетов/мобильников на клиенте?

4. При заполнении формы устройство автоматически увеличивает масштаб для облегчения заполнения этой формы. Можно ли по окончанию заполнения (нажатию enter, ok или аналога) каким-либо образом задать устройству предшествующий масштаб(т.е. есть ли у мобильных устройств интерфейс для работы со scale и есть ли подходящее событие завершения редактирования формы?).

От бутстрапа было решено отказаться в силу некоторых причин, и возвращаться к нему просто нет времени.

Comment: баунти в 500 репутации за любой ответ, который поможет решить любую из задач!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вопрос риторический, без кода и устройства ответить, думаю, нереально.

2) Должен подчиняться css media query landscape и portrait 100% проверено

3) Я использую http://matthewhudson.me/projects/device.js/ совместно с:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) { } 
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) { }
```

Также касательно размещения объекта относительно window: обычно делаю `.wrapper`, который `position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%;` со свойством `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`, и уже внутри него "лепится" сайт.

4) Нет, только запретить масштабирование полностью: `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">`

P.S. Не претендую на идеальный ответ, не гонюсь за рейтингом, просто делюсь с автором своими наработками.

Comment: Отлично, попробую. По первому вопросу - там примерно такой код у дива-враппера:

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    // пробовал right: 0; - результат аналогичный
    padding: 8px 13px

> Должен подчиняться css media query landscape и portrait 100% проверено

Здесь бы подробнее. Если я задам два идентичных правила для landscape/portrait, это все равно вызовет перерисовку?

Comment: 1. По идее, всё норм, эмулятор в хроме ведёт себя так же? Там очень удобно играться со стилями, может быть, "вправо" за враппер выступает какой блок? Я бы попробовал родителю `overflow:hidden;` если возможно, и ещё полезно `fixed` элементам задавать что-то типа `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` очень часто избавляет от неестественного поведения.

2. Будет ли перерисовка, мне сказать сложно, но то что стили применяться из другого куска CSS это точно.